# AES NI and Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, aes, masm

This might be a totally ignoramus question, but here goes.

I have an unmanaged DLL project built in Visual Studio C/C++. It includes some C modules and some ASM modules. Among other things it implements AES using the old Brian Gladman code. I want to add support for AES-NI on supported processors. Does Visual Studio implement any of the AES-NI instructions either in C or ASM?  I have several different versions of Visual Studio, the latest being 2017. Thanks.

Comment: MSVC supports most of Intel's intrinsics with `#include <immintrin.h>`.  https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=aes.